# Are there any Google Chrome extensions for inserting Furigana over Kanji?

Tags: google-chrome, software-rec, google-chrome-extensions, language, japanese

Are there any Google Chrome extensions or userscripts for automatically inserting Furigana characters over Kanji in web pages?

*Please don't suggest [Furigana Injector](https://code.google.com/p/furigana-injector/), because it doesn't work and is not documented.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IPA furigana](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ipa-furigana/jnnbgnfnncobhklficfkdnclohaklifi?hl=en) extension.